# Dynamically setting default url in asp.net forms authentication

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Here is my problem

I have two login control in the index page of my website,each of two different usertypes.

```
there are two user types brands and creatives.
the branded user will log in to brands bin(brandsbin.aspx)
the Creative user will sign in to creativebin(creativebin.aspx)
```

i am using forms authentication for signin.
so i am confused here to to rediret to default path for each user types.
how to set default page for each user types.

in the web config file i have added like this

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms name="forms" loginUrl="Index.aspx" defaultUrl="brandsbin.aspx" path="/" timeout="15" slidingExpiration="true"></forms>
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should redirect from the login page (Index.aspx) to two different pages depending on the user type. You could have Login1 and Login2 for example and those pages have to be set as publicly available for everyone in the web.config, this to avoid that after your redirect to any of those pages IIS brings you back to index.aspx.